# Why does this hex value get output as a negative number?

Tags: c++, c

```
char buffer_b[5] = { 0xDA, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x07 };
printf("%d\n%d\n%d", buffer_b[0], buffer_b[2], buffer_b[4]);
```

This gives me output:

```
-38
4
7
```

However I am expecting:

```
218
4
7
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

char is signed.  Use unsigned char.

use %ud also.

Comment: `char` is not always signed. If it matters, you should be explicit either way (with `signed` or `unsigned`). Or, even better, use `uint8_t`.

Comment: Don't cast the buffer type, just make it unsigned to start with.

Comment: can't, the data comes from some other library function

Answer (score 8):

Evidently, `char` is signed in your environment. (That's a detail that can vary from one implementation to the next, and some compilers even offer you an option through a command-line switch.) The number you're printing is 0xDA, which has the most significant bit set, so its value is negative. When the compiler passes that value to `printf`, it promotes the (signed) char value to type `int`, and it retains its negativity. You used the `%d` format string, which tells `printf` to interpret its argument as a signed value.

To treat the value as unsigned, you should at a minimum use the `%u` format string. Then either change your array's element type to be an unsigned type, such as `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, or type-cast the `printf` argument to `unsigned`.

Comment: I will sometimes mask the value to make sure the conversion to `unsigned` doesn't sign extend first, i.e. `buffer_b[0] & 0xff`.

Answer (score 2):

When the `char` `0xDA` is promoted to `int` to pass to `printf`, the compiler is doing a sign-extension, converting it to `0xffffffda`, which is the 32-bit representation of `-38`.  You were expecting it to be zero-extended to `0x000000da`.  To control how the compiler extends a character, you have declare it as `signed char` or `unsigned char`.  Signed integer types are widened by sign-extending, and unsigned integer types are widened by zero-extending.

You can't predict how any particular compiler will treat an unqualified `char`, or if it will be the same in the next release of the compiler.